# Is there a Codeigniter library that can automatically generate a QR code with a custom logo in the center?

Tags: customization, qr-code, codeigniter-2

Is there a Codeigniter library that can automatically generate a QR code with my website's logo in the center?

Comment: excuse me with my english .. i cant speak english well i am indonesian :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This library might help; it also includes some examples (updated in January 2012) - https://github.com/dwisetiyadi/CodeIgniter-PHP-QR-Code